# Accessing Method in different class Same name space without instantiating the class Reference Only

Tags: c#

is there a way to access a method in defferent class with same name space

Sample Codes

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using WindowsFormsApplication1;


namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public void Test()
        {

        }
    }
}


namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public class TestClass
    {
        public void Test2()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

I wabt to access test2() method inside Test() method they are in different class but in same namespace i want to access it without instantiating the TestClass class like this

```
TestClass test = new TestClass();
test.Test2();
```

i dont want to do it that way is there a way?

NOTE " I am avoiding to use a static Method" thank you for the answering this

Comment: No, there is no way. That is, unless you have `Form1` inherit from `TestClass`... Why are you "avoiding to use a static method"?

Comment: Agree with @SimonWhitehead. Inheritance is the only way.

Comment: a lot of conflict is going to appear in my current project the code that i provided is just an example in my current project the the method that i need to access has a non static member if im going to change it to static i think it will explode my code hahaha

Comment: What about inheriting the TestClass?

Comment: can you provide me some codes?

Comment: @bRaNdOn Not sure if I understand you right, but if you need to access instance member in a static method, you can pass instance of TestClass as a parameter to that static method. You can even make it extension method ("this" keyword before TestClass parameter) for a more convenient syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AS far as I know, there is no way to do it. **But** why would you want to?

To access Test() you're instantiating a class (Form1). You want then to use a different method but not instantiate the class. So what would be the meaning of running it? What would be its context?

Possible solutions:

1. Create an extension method (since you'll be extending Form, I don't recommend it)
2. Move Test2() into Form1
3. Move test() into TestClass, and instantiate it only once.
4. Use a static class after all

Comment: static method i see. i dont prefer that HmmMMm i think i just need to alter my solution for this one